# Apache doesn't start with an error

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django application in AWS with EC2-Instance.

Actually, I'm following this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04

When I followed all and so command 'sudo service apache2 start'

I got an error :

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

I did check the log with the command `'systemctl status apache2.service'`

> apache2[18041]:  * The apache2
>   configtest failed.
>
> apache2[18041]:
>   Output of config test was:
>
> apache2[18041]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of
>   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
>
> apache2[18041]: Multiple  arguments not
>   (yet) supported.
>   apache2[18041]: Action
>   'configtest' failed.
>
> apache2[18041]:
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

`'etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf'` is below

```
</VirtualHost>
        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT /static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess MY_PROJECT python-path=/home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT python-home=/home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/sn_venv
        WSGIProcessGroup MY_PROJECT
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: /home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT /static  extra space

Comment: Side note: there is no need to add `please help me!` to all of your questions. This is just fluff that will be removed by editors in the long term, since readers generally prefer succinct questions here. It's worth noting also that since it is obvious that you need help, explicitly saying so may be read as a form of begging, and downvotes may result. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing

```
sudo a2enmod yourReleventProtocolName
```

In my case when

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

command fix the above error for ssl

Comment: This looks like a comment and not an answer to me

Comment: Sorry about that. But I don't have reputation to comment on your question. So I was only left with sharing this experience with you as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is from the very first line

```
</VirtualHost>
```

change it to `<VirtualHost>`

if the problem persist, run

```
apachectl configtest
```

and it will help you know where the problems are coming from